# Safe navigation operator with bracket property accesor

Tags: angular, properties, safe-navigation-operator

I've run into a case where I can't use the dot notation to access a property, because the property's name contains a dot.

I have an object called `translations` whose properties contain string translations, for example the `Tooltip.O2` property contains the translation for the tooltip of an image:

```
<img [matTooltip]="translations?.Tooltip.O2" [src]="bed.additionalO2 ? medO2 : noO2">
```

When I do this, it thinks I'm trying to access a `Tooltip` object inside `translations` with an `O2` property. I'm aware that I can use the bracket notation to access it:

```
[matTooltip]="translations['Tooltip.O2']"
```

However, it does not seem like the safe navigation operator `?` can be used with the bracket notation. I've tried to write `translations?['Tooltip.O2']`, but it caused errors.

I would like to know if there is there a way to access the property using the dot notation, or if there is a way to use the safe navigtaion operator with the bracket notation?

Answer (score 6):

There is a way to use safe navigation operator with bracket notation. Actually safe navigation operator is officialy called optional chaining operator. Syntax from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

> obj.val?.prop
> obj.val?.[expr]
> obj.arr?.[index]
> obj.func?.(args)

So in your case you need to use `translations?.['Tooltip.O2']`.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was the following:

```
[matTooltip]="translations ? translations['Tooltip.O2'] : null"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you initialize the translations obj? It would avoid any error.

```
translations = {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional operator for `null` check

```
[matTooltip]="translations ? translations['Tooltip.O2'] : null"
```